# Storing Date Value in MYSQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I try to store OffsetDateTime value in MySQL DB

> 2020-02-05T10:17:41.703Z

It is adding server timeZone i.e, +5.30 to the given time and storing it

> 2020-02-05 15:47:41.703

How can i store the date value without any addition of timezone

Comment: How your column declared in db table?

Comment: Redefine the column as DATETIME instead of TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Akina --
When I Change to TIMESTAMP also its storing the same value
It is adding +5.30 to the given date

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If you check the docs you can find out how datetime and timestamp fields are handled differently with respect to time zones and automatic conversions. [link to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)    As of MySQL 8.0.19, you can specify a time zone offset when inserting TIMESTAMP and DATETIME values into a table.